# New site description

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Now that we've had some time in beta, we're looking at solidifying our site description.

This is what we've come up with:

> This site is for artists, crafters, and hobbyists interested in creating handmade, tangible works.

It gets right to the point! It's for a variety of users, and it's clear that it's about the process of making things (and not, say, art history). "Tangible" means we're generally excluding digital works, but also things such as dance and music.

Let us know what you think!

---

Our description in the tour page now reads:

> Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange is for artists and crafters, from professionals to hobbyists, who are interested in creating handmade, tangible works. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about traditional artwork and handmade items.

Which combines the top-rated current answer with some slight changes discussed in the comments.

This change need not be permanent, if community opinion changes.

Comment: I think that this description is *considerably* better because I finally find myself in the "hobbyist" part (and that makes me happy :). However, while the definition of *artist* and *crafter* are still not completely clear to me I'm fearing that *hobby* is even less clear. As an example: [covering books](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/183/how-can-i-cover-books-with-contact-paper-without-bubbles) was a hobby for me during a long time.

Comment: @Surb I think the intent of "hobbyist" is to allow for amateur as well as professional artists rather than broadening the scope to hobbies such as stamp collecting etc...

Comment: I think hobbyist is along the lines of what Catija is saying and the scope is clarified by _creating handmade, tangible works._ Tangible is great word choice to convey our sites meaning.

Answer (score 5):

I very much like the sentence as suggested but I worry that, as the comments show, the term "hobbyist" may be confusing. An alternate option would be the slightly more wordy suggestion:

> "This site is for artists and crafters at both the professional and hobbyist levels who are interested in creating handmade, tangible works."

This makes it clear that "hobbyist" relates to whether someone does this craft for fun (as opposed to professionally) rather than running the risk of broadening the scope of topics to all "hobbies".

Comment: It can't hurt to add this but _I_ don't think it is necessary. Hobby should imply a leisure activity and _handmade, tangible works_ should sufficient limit the scope.

Comment: Maybe "...crafters, from beginners to professionals, ..."? Seems less of a mouthful.

Comment: @CreationEdge I'm not a huge fan of emphasizing beginners... I could do "from hobbyists to professionals," though.

Comment: I guess it's all semantics, but there was some confusion earlier about what hobbyist meant (such as train hobbyist?). i don't think we can make it perfect, though.

Comment: @CreationEdge You're right, but I think that how it's set apart, with commas and specifically contrasts with "professionals" removes that ambiguity. We could further emphasize that by reversing the order to "From professionals to hobbyists".

Comment: Could we not just say "all skill levels"? Or is there potential ambiguity there?

Answer (score -1):

### This is a wonderful one-liner that we should be using.

The inclusion of "hobbyists" lets people know that we are not a professional-only site. We welcome users of all skill levels.

I applaud the use of the word "tangible" in the description as that conveys the meaning of our scope perfectly and I doubt that will be changing in the days to come.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a version avoiding the profressional/hobbyist problem but keeping arts in crafts in it.

> "This site is for people interested in creating handmade, tangible works of art and crafts."

However, this version is less wordy but the same meaning.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a version avoiding the professional/hobbyist problem.

> "This site is for people interested in creating handmade, tangible works."

Comment: You also removed artist and crafters.... Now it reads as making _anything_